# Which Scikit-learn application should I use in order to process my data? (Python)

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-science-model

I am writing a program that will take a multitude of data, such as chlorophyll levels, water temperature, nitrogen/phosphorous levels, etc., in order to predict the growth of algae in a body of water. There are many factors that could affect the growth of algae. Because of this, I do not know which application I should use in the Scikit-learn library in order to accommodate all of the different columns. The algae level is one of the columns. To be more specific, there are 17 other columns that I want to account for (Half of which are identifiers for if the data is likely to be incorrect). What should I use in order to account for all of the columns?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not well defined. I suppose you want to estimate/predict the growth based on some explanatory variables, so $y(X)$. First you need to define what $y$ actually is, an (absolute) amount or a growth rate?

You can for instance formulate a linear model like:

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 + X + u$$
to measure the absolute amount of $y$ contingent on some $X$. Alternatively, you can also look at how $y$ changes, when $X$ changes by using a $log$ transformation on either $y$ or $X$. See [this](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqhow-do-i-interpret-a-regression-model-when-some-variables-are-log-transformed/) for more details. To apply such models, you would generally use [linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).

However, if you are simply up to making a prediction (and you are not necessarily interested in interpreting regression coefficients in order to find average marginal effects of $X$ on $y$), you can use [many different model types in sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html).

It is standard to include several explanatory variables ($X$), so this is not an issue. See the various sklearn examples, such as [this one](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-ols-py).

If you are simply up to prediction, you may start with a [random forest regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) (since this is most robust and often works well). First, split your data into a [train and test set](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). Second, run a random forest on the train set, Third, test your model based on the test set.